# Microsoft SQL Server connection error with Visual Studio.net (Windows forms)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying for a while to connect the database to `visualstudio.net` and it just doesn't work.

First I made the database and made everything I needed there and when I tried connecting it in visual.net through datagridview (trying to get it displayed there) it only gives me access to the "System databases" in which I can't make a database.

After that I decided to make the tables under the "master" database to see if that worked and yeah I can select the database and everything but it says it's empty when I know it's not. It says it has no tables when I've checked multiple times and saw the tables I've created there.

I would appreciate some help to either be able to get for visual to accept a database I make (to be able to automatically detect it once I enter the server name) or to see how can I use the master one properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data source to your project and it will be able to connect to the user databases. Also, it is highly inadvisable to create any user objects in the master database.

Comment: Is it possible for you to please share some screen grabs to better understand the issue at hand?

Answer (score 0):

master database is a system database and you should not create user objects in the system database. In the connection string, provide the user database name explicitly. If you dont provide the database name, it defaults to master database.

Refer to [connection strings for Sql Server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) for providing the right connection string for SQL Server in .net.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. I can't provide the database because it doesn't let me choose any rather than the master and the other ones the sql server makes. If I try choosing it directly it tells me it's being used by sql and can't be opened by .net and if I close sql it still tells me the same thing.